# What is the optimal way to convert a `usize` to a `&str`?

Tags: rust

I need to convert a `usize` to a `&str` to pass to a `fn foo(&str)`. I found the following two ways, but don't know if there is a difference between using `as_str()` or `Deref`. Maybe the work done by `self` in `as_str` links with `Deref` somehow? I do not know if it may be better to use one or the other or if they actually are the same.

1. Using `temp.to_string().as_str()`:

   ```
   #[inline]
   #[stable(feature = "string_as_str", since = "1.7.0")]
   pub fn as_str(&self) -> &str {
       self
   }
   ```
2. Using `&*temp.to_string()` or `&temp.to_string()`. This works via `Deref`:

   ```
   #[stable(feature = "rust1", since = "1.0.0")]
   impl ops::Deref for String {
       type Target = str;

       #[inline]
       fn deref(&self) -> &str {
           unsafe { str::from_utf8_unchecked(&self.vec) }
       }
   }
   ```

> The question may depend on what you want to do in foo: does the passed
>   `&str` need to outlive `foo` or not ?

`foo(&str)` is a minimal example for `s: &str` in this code:

```
extern crate termbox_sys as termbox;

pub fn print(&self, x: usize, y: usize, sty: Style, fg: Color, bg: Color, s: &str) {
    let fg = Style::from_color(fg) | (sty & style::TB_ATTRIB);
    let bg = Style::from_color(bg);
    for (i, ch) in s.chars().enumerate() {
        unsafe {
            self.change_cell(x + i, y, ch as u32, fg.bits(), bg.bits());
        }
    }
}

pub unsafe fn change_cell(&self, x: usize, y: usize, ch: u32, fg: u16, bg: u16) {
    termbox::tb_change_cell(x as c_int, y as c_int, ch, fg, bg)
}
```

[termbox_sys](https://github.com/gchp/termbox-sys/blob/master/lib.rs)

Comment: @malbarbo `to_string()` return a `String` I use `&*` for `&str` I think I need `&*` in this case. But not if this is the best way?.

Comment: you are right, I rushed on this. If `foo` was a method, the `temp.to_string().foo()` would do an auto deref to `&str`, but `foo` is a function, so `&*` is necessary. The `usize` to `String` conversion is the right way.

Comment: What are we optimizing for?

Answer (score 2):

As you noticed, `as_str` doesn't appear to do anything. In fact it returns `self`, a `&String`, where a `&str` is expected. This causes the compiler to insert a call to `Deref`. So your two ways are exactly the same.

Answer (score 1):

To convert the usize to &str you can first convet it into the String

```
value.to_string().as_str()
```

This is the simplest way, both the ways you mentioned use deref coercion one use internally and one you define explicitly.

> Deref coercion converts a reference to a type that implements the
> Deref trait into a reference to another type. For example, deref
> coercion can convert &String to &str because String implements the
> Deref trait such that it returns &str. Deref coercion is a convenience
> Rust performs on arguments to functions and methods, and works only on
> types that implement the Deref trait. It happens automatically when we
> pass a reference to a particular type’s value as an argument to a
> function or method that doesn’t match the parameter type in the
> function or method definition. A sequence of calls to the deref method
> converts the type we provided into the type the parameter needs.